# Makine a composite foreign key that refers to two differnt tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a schema for a hospital data base. I have 4 tables, candidate details, hospital details, position details and interview details. The interview table has a foreign key referring to the candidate table, one to the position's table and I also want it to have one referring to the hospital table but I noticed that it is possible then to have a tuple where the combination of the position id and the hospital id is not the same as the combination that occurs on the position tables (the position table has a foreign key referring to the hospital table) So in other words is makes it possible to enter the incorrect hospital id or position id in the interview table. So for instance on the interview table I could enter a tuple where the position id is 01 and the hospital id is 02 but if you go the positions table, the position id that is being refereed to could easily have a hospital id that is different (eg 03).

I was thinking that there might be away of creating a composite foreign key that refers to two different tables at the same time. If that's not the case, is the only way of resolving the issue, just removing the hospital id column from the interview table completely?

I've been using mySQL workbench so I don't have any of the SQL code on hand but if any extra information (eg ERR image) is required to answer this question I'll try my best to source it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer :** 
**No**, a foreign key constraint always references exactly **one** parent table.

However, If I understand your situation well, you have 4 tables

```
candidate details. id
hospital details. id
position details. id, hospital_id
interview details. candidate_id, hospital_id, position_id
```

The problem is the relation between postion and hospital is many to many

*simple way EAV* add another table call it hospital_postition, that has all the positions in all hospitals then link each hospital_postition to the condidate in the interview

```
candidate details. id
hospital details. id
position details. id
hospital_postition. id, hospital_id, position_id
interview details. candidate_id, hospital_position_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Less is more!

You have this problem because the table isn't in 3rd normal form. hospital_id isn't dependent on the interview, it's dependent on the position, and position_id is not the KEY for this able.

Ask yourself, do I really want to record hospital_id in the interview table? All the information you probably need is already stored in the positions table. The only reason I can think of for wanting that column would be where you were conducting interviews in hospitals other than the one where the position is based. If that is the case then your schema is already correct but your question implies otherwise.

Drop the hospital_id column from the interview table and your problem will magically disappear.

On the subject of getting table definitions (SQL code) out of MySQL Workbench, try this:

- Right-click the table name in the schema browser
- Select "Send to SQL Editor"
- Select "Create statement"